# is there any open source library or code project to implement the airplay in android?

Tags: android, iphone, airplay

is there any open source library or code project  to implement the airplay in the android ? I want to make android as a server (Airplay receiver).

Comment: why down vote ? at least give some reason for downvoting ? without reason it doesn't matter for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It al depends on that you want to share on which device.

You can use [Anymote Library](http://code.google.com/p/googletv-android-samples/source/browse/#git%2FAnymoteLibrary) in your Android application to connect and communicate with Google TV using the [Anymote protocol](https://developers.google.com/tv/remote/docs/anymote).

Comment: actually  i want android as a receiver . Which receive the stream from the iOS device

Comment: then the answer is no, there is no open source that can do that.

Comment: +1 for your valuable reply .